# simple explanation of ampers, voltage, watts, current and electricitiy

Tags: learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an amp (and other such basic questions) in the simplest possible terms?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6312/what-is-an-amp-and-other-such-basic-questions-in-the-simplest-possible-terms)

How can can this terms be simplified or what are some basic analogy.

let say I have a 9 volts motor. what happens If I put use a 12 volts battery, or what happens if I use a 9 volts battery and it's ampers are really high. Can an air be a conductor of electricity? Can it be like radio waves or wifi that even without a wire/conductor it can travel?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6312/what-is-an-amp-and-other-such-basic-questions-in-the-simplest-possible-terms